# PyCharm doesn't run files calles "main.py"?

Tags: python, pycharm

Sorry, this is driving me crazy. I just started using PyCharm, and have gone through the normal steps to create a Python project. PyCharm creates a default file called "main.py". However, PyCharm does not seem to know that this is a Python file, despite the ".py" extension in its name.

1. The text formatting color highlights in the text editor don't work.
2. There is no option to Run this file.

However - **when I add a new Python file manually to this project with a **different name**, everything works fine.** However, when I create a file called "main.py", nothing works, as described above. When I create a new Python file with a different name, and then rename it to "main.py", it doesn't work again.

Why is this happening? I've searched for this problem but haven't found an applicable solution. Why does PyCharm doing something weird to files called "main.py" specifically?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. PyCharm doesn't treat files called `main.py` differently, so your problem is probably somewhere else. Maybe share some detail about the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Shift+F10,
should automatically edit the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

to add to the previous answer: you can also right click on the file and choose "Run 'main'", which automatically creates a configuration with the project interpreter for that file.

Another thing you can check is your interpreter settings and ideally make sure its using venv, this way packages you install don't go into global and are kept on a project basis.